# Can anyone please explain me the code?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
rect.setAttribute('x',5);
rect.setAttribute('y',5);
rect.setAttribute('width',500);
rect.setAttribute('height',500);
rect.setAttribute('fill','#95B3D7');
svg.appendChild(rect);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: What is your concern here?

Comment: An rectangle is created in SVG using JavaScript. Get to know SVG - https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Comment: couldnt understand the first three lines

Comment: **Line 1:** Create a `svg` element(`<svg>`). http://www.w3.org/2000/svg refers to the SVG definition by w3.org **Line 2:** Get the svg NameSpace **Line 3:** Create a rectangle as per the definition in SVG NameSpace

Comment: can we use the same namespace(svgNS in this case) to draw other objects(for eg: circle,paths,etc), or do i need to create a separate namespace for each of these drawings?

Comment: You need to use the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The code just creates an SVG Image, which is a rectangle of dimensions 500x500 with the color of #95B3D7.

Comment: can you be more specific for each of the first three lines? what is happening in each line?

Comment: First line is definition of svg from w3 standard.  Second is to get XML namespace for svg drawing. Third is to create rectangle using that Namespace by creating a varaiable

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines are a little redundant.

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
```

The third line creates an SVG `<rect>` element.

```
var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
```

You need to use `createElementNS()` for this because SVG elements have a different namespace from HTML elements.  So using the simpler version as follows...

```
var rect = document.createElement('rect');
```

...will not work. That is because it is creating an HTML element called `rect`, and not an SVG one.